# Kendo UI Dropdown, making the drop down panel wider than the control

Tags: css, kendo-ui

In a Kendo UI Dropdown, is it possible to make the drop down panel wider than the control?

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/gridview/how-to-specify-width-of-gridviewcomboboxcolumn-drop-down.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `id` of the `dropDownList` is `drop`, you need to define a CSS style as:

```
#drop-list { 
    width: 300px !important;
}
```

for overwriting KendoUI computed width and set it to (in this example) `300px`.

Comment: After trying this out, I have two comments for others that may read this:  I had to use #drop-list {   width: 300px !important;  }.  Do NOT assume that Kendo dropdown list is NEXT to your original drop down list (the one with id of drop) when creating your new CSS for the list because it is not.  With version 2015.1.318 of Kendo, it appears that the list is at the bottom of the HTML document (outside my originally bound DIV).

Answer (score 6):

Another possible approach:

```
var dropdownlist = $("#titles").data("kendoDropDownList");

// set width of the drop-down list
dropdownlist.list.width(400);
```

Code snippet is taken from the official examples ([link](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/template.html)).

Comment: This worked a charm for me, thank you, sasheto. The `dropdownlist.list.width(400);` makes the dropdown panel have a different width than the control box itself.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there's a command for that:

`$("#idOfMyDropDownList").data("kendoDropDownList").list.width("auto");`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
$("[data-role=dropdownlist]").each(function () {
  $(this).data("kendoDropDownList").list.width(300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set this directly when defining the control with:

```
.AutoWidth(true)
```

i.e.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
  .Name("ddl")
  .DataTextField("Text")
  .DataValueField("Value")
  .AutoWidth(true)
  .BindTo(Model.list))
```