# Kendo UI MVVM Dropdownlist - dropdown list wider than control itself

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI MVVM dropdownlist, and I want the width of the list to be wider than the control itself.

```
<input class="dropDowns" data-role="dropdownlist" style="width: auto;" />
```

I found an solution: 
[Kendo UI Dropdown, making the drop down panel wider than the control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128753/kendo-ui-dropdown-making-the-drop-down-panel-wider-than-the-control)
But I can't apply this to my MVVM example.

Comment: What did you attempt? Why can't you use a simple CSS rule to do this for you?

Comment: I haven't really attempted anything other that setting the style of the width - which makes the whole control bigger.  Maybe there is a way to use a simple CSS rule, but if so, I don't know what it would be.  I guess I also tried to give the input and ID of dropdown and use this: dropdown.list.width(400); but list is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can't set the list width based on the class, you have to give it an id.

```
<input id="dropDowns" data-role="dropdownlist" style="width: auto;" />
```

Then the jQuery:

```
$("#dropDowns").data("kendoDropDownList").list.width(400);
```

Comment: Another solution:   $("[data-role=dropdownlist]").each(function () {
       $(this).data("kendoDropDownList").list.width(300);
      });

Comment: for me setting style="width:400px" on the input woked

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution without using the Id

```
$("[data-role=dropdownlist]").each(function () {
  $(this).data("kendoDropDownList").list.width(300);
});
```